How to Retrieve Key Performance Metrics from SAP ASE / Sybase Instances?
I want to fetch important performance metrics from SAP ASE/Sybase databases. These include:

Percent of lock used
Percent of active connections
Heap Memory Utilization %
Memory Utilization %
Disk Utilization % by Logical Disk

I've looked into Sybase's built-in monitoring tables, but couldn't find these specific metrics there.
Can anyone suggest a way to help me gather this information from Sybase databases? I've searched around but haven't found a clear solution yet.
Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
